# java spring filling form with values at first request

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, modelandview

Hallo,

I am using a extended `SimpleFormController` and I override the  `formBackingObject`-method. In my jsp form I would like to access the object from `formBackingObject`, but I can't find any way to touch it. `ModelAndView` lets you give the object (model) a name, that it can be accessed by in the jsp (with EL or taglibs). This concept is missing here.

Is `formBackingObject` the wrong method to override or am I just to stupid to access the object in jsps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy:

I'm doing it the right way, annotation would be a different valid approach.

The solution was to give the bean a commandName property in the app-servlet.xml.